# in flutter application, i have image stretch problem when using flutter_pptx plugin or dart_pptx package

Tags: flutter, dart, powerpoint

I am making a flutter application that gathers information of the shift and extract them to a PowerPoint application with slides contain text and slides contains images.
the problem is in photo slides pictures it gets distorted and stretched.
I'm using the dart_pptx package.
this is the code i'm emplimenting :

```
Future makeSlide(BuildContext context) async {
    try{
      final pres = PowerPoint();
     
      pres.addTitleSlide(
        title: 'Les Admissions ( ${admissionList.length} )'.toTextValue(),
      );

      for(Patient p in admissionList){
        pres
            .addTitleAndBulletsSlide(
          title: '${p.name} ${p.age} ans'.toTextValue(),

          bullets: [
            'ATCD : ${p.atcd}',
            p.number != 0 ? 'N° : ${p.atcd}' : '',
            'HDM : ${p.hdm}',
            ' ',
            ' ',
            'Dg : ${p.diagnostique}',
          ].map((e) => e.toTextValue()).toList(),
        );
        List<String> picturepathList = p.pictures!.split(',');
        for(String picturepath in picturepathList){
          pres.addPhotoSlide(
            image: ImageReference(
              path: picturepath,
              name: '${UniqueKey().hashCode}',
            ),
          );
        }

      }
     
      Directory? directory = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Download');
      if (!await directory.exists()) {
        directory = await getDownloadsDirectory();
      }

      String? s = directory?.path;

      final file = File('$s/Garde.pptx');
      bool fileExists = await file.exists();

      // If the file exists, delete it
      if (fileExists) {
        await file.delete();
      }

      final bytes = await pres.save();
      if(bytes != null){
        var i = await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);

        if (i != null) {
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                backgroundColor: myColor2,
                title: Text('File',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: myColor3),),
                content: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),color: myColor2,),height: 150,

                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0,bottom: 8.0),
                    child: Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),color: myColor2),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          openfilesFromPath(i.path);
                        },
                        child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text('Open With WPS Office!',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10,color: Colors.red),),
                            Card(elevation: 2,color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2),
                              child: ListTile(
                                title: Text('Garde du ${gardeDate}.pptx',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                                subtitle: Text('File Path : ${i.path}' ,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 10),),
                                leading: Image.asset(pictureasset.Assets.imagesPowerpointicon,),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                  ),
                ),
                actions: <Widget>[

                  GestureDetector(onTap: () async {
                    final result = await Share.shareXFiles([XFile('${i.path}')], text: 'Garde du ${gardeDate}.pptx');
                    if (result.status == ShareResultStatus.success) {
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        SnackBar(
                          content: Text('Thank you for sharing'),
                        ),
                      );
                    }

                  },
                      child: Container(height: 50,width: 50,child: Icon(Icons.share,color: Colors.white),decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),)),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {

                        Navigator.of(context).pop();} ,
                      child: Text('Close',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: myColor3),),),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          );

        } else {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(
              content: Text('Somthing went wrong'),
            ),
          );
        }
      }

      notifyListeners();
    }
    catch (e){
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('Somthing Wrong Happened!'),
        ),
      );
    }


  }
```

in the /template/ppt/slides/photo.xml.mustache.dart file :

```
/// This file is generated, do not edit!
/// See `bin/copy.dart` for more information.

/// Path: ./template/ppt/slides/photo.xml.mustache
const String template = r'''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:sld xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"
    xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
    xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main"
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math"
    xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main" showMasterSp="1" showMasterPhAnim="1">
    <p:cSld>
        {{>slide-background}}
        <p:spTree>
            <p:nvGrpSpPr>
                <p:cNvPr id="1" name=""/>
                <p:cNvGrpSpPr/>
                <p:nvPr/>
            </p:nvGrpSpPr>
            <p:grpSpPr>
                <a:xfrm>
                    <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
                    <a:ext cx="0" cy="0"/>
                    <a:chOff x="0" y="0"/>
                    <a:chExt cx="0" cy="0"/>
                </a:xfrm>
            </p:grpSpPr>
            <p:pic>
                <p:nvPicPr>
                    {{#image}}
                    <p:cNvPr id="{{new-id}}" name="{{image.name}}" descr="{{image.description}}"/>
                    {{/image}}
                    {{^image}}
                    <p:cNvPr id="{{new-id}}" name="Image" descr="Image"/>
                    {{/image}}
                    <p:cNvPicPr>
                        <a:picLocks noChangeAspect="1"/>
                    </p:cNvPicPr>
                    <p:nvPr>
                        <p:ph type="pic" idx="21"/>
                    </p:nvPr>
                </p:nvPicPr>
                <p:blipFill>
                    <a:blip r:embed="rId{{imageId1}}">
                        <a:extLst/>
                    </a:blip>
                    <a:stretch>
                        <a:fillRect/>
                    </a:stretch>
                </p:blipFill>
                <p:spPr>
                    <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                        <a:avLst/>
                    </a:prstGeom>
                </p:spPr>
            </p:pic>
            {{>speaker-notes}}
        </p:spTree>
    </p:cSld>
    <p:clrMapOvr>
        <a:masterClrMapping/>
    </p:clrMapOvr>
    <p:transition xmlns:p14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2010/main" spd="med" advClick="1"/>
</p:sld>
```

i tried changing :

```
                <p:blipFill>
                    <a:blip r:embed="rId{{imageId1}}">
                        <a:extLst/>
                    </a:blip>
                    <a:stretch>
                        <a:fillRect/>
                    </a:stretch>
                </p:blipFill>
```

to this :

```
                <p:blipFill dpi="96">
                    <a:blip r:embed="rId{{imageId1}}">
                        <a:extLst/>
                    </a:blip>
                    <a:srcRect/>
                </p:blipFill>
```

i would still have the same problem i want the photo to keep its ratio